# eclipse refuses to run my android project after I edit widget xml

Tags: java, android, xml, widget

I change few things in widget xml.

Then I build successfully. Then I try to run, but get an error:

btw, horizonalt widget is regular xml or lansdcap xaml?

[image]

But clean and re-build runs OK

Answer (score 3):

Try below things, may be your issue will be solved.

- `Go to window > show view>error logs`. Display error logs if you have any. Try to clean project / build it & restart eclipse.
- `Go to window > show view> Problems`.This will show list of errors `select all` and `delete` and Try to clean project / build it & restart eclipse.
- If there is any error, then it will show in `Logcat > Error`

Some times Editor doesn't show up latest update and holding older or garbage value.

Comment: I have native code as well. So my `problems` view is always filled

Comment: are you using ant `lib` in your app or is there any `red cross` through out `project dir` ?

Comment: I added the `egit` plug in and it runs over the red crosses :( do you know how they can co-live aside

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33961/room-for-chintan-khetiya-and-elad-benda

Answer (score 1):

Go to window>show view>error logs. Display error logs if you have any. Try to clean project / build it & restart eclipse.